# SlideRight and SlideLeft jQuery issue

Tags: jquery

I want when i clicked on one item, to show a div and slide it right. When i clicked on the other item i want to hide that div or slide it left. How can i do that?

This is mycode:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".sidePanel").hide();
        $(".trigger-reverse").hide();
        $(".trigger").css("margin-left","-15px");

        $(".trigger").click(function() {  //slide right

            $(this).hide();
            $(".trigger-reverse").show();
            $(".sidePanel").show();
        });
        $(".trigger-reverse").click(function() {   // slide left
            $(this).hide();
            $(".trigger").show();
            $(this).css("margin-left","0px");
            $(".sidePanel").hide();
        });
     });
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/

Comment: Please also provide the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had taken a div and two buttons with button ids **button1** and **button2**

```
$("#button1").click(function () {

// Set the effect type
var effect = 'slide';

// Set the options for the effect type chosen
var options = { direction: "left" };

// Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
var duration = 500;

$('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});

$("#button2").click(function () {

// Set the effect type
var effect = 'slide';

// Set the options for the effect type chosen
var options = { direction: "right" };

// Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
var duration = 500;

$('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

please check the similar scenario in  [fiddler here](http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/2561/) i hope this will meet your requirement. i hope my answer is helpful

Comment: Don't forget you need to use jQuery and **jQuery UI** for this to work